# Swift save 16 bit depth image from builtInDualCamera

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera, truedepth-camera

I can get depth's CVPixelBuffer from the camera session. How to save it as a 16 bit png without losing depth data?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628895/save-the-depth-data-with-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum), it helped me saving the depth images as UIImage to my camera roll. I am currently also struggling to convert it to 16 bit, since it always saves it as a 32 bit Image.
I'll keep you posted once I find out how it works.