# Save the depth data with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: swift, uiimage, cvpixelbuffer

I am using ARKit 4 (+MetalKit) with the new iPhone device, and I am trying to access the depth data (from the LiDAR) and save it as the depth map along with the actual RGB image. While I have seen many demos showing it, non showed the code for actually visualising the depth map. I have made a button, and this is the code that is used with it:

```
func saveCapturedBuffer(buffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    let depthCIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)
    let context: CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
    let depthCGImage: CGImage = context.createCGImage(depthCIImage, from: depthCIImage.extent)!
    let depthUIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: depthCGImage)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(depthUIImage, self, #selector(saveError), nil)
    }

@objc func capture(sender: UIButton) {
    let frame: ARFrame = session.currentFrame!
    guard let depthData =  frame.sceneDepth ?? frame.sceneDepth else { return }
    var pixelBufferDepth: CVPixelBuffer!
    pixelBufferDepth = depthData.depthMap
    saveCapturedBuffer(buffer: pixelBufferDepth)
    
    var capturedImageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer!
    capturedImageBuffer = frame.capturedImage
    print(CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(capturedImageBuffer))
    saveCapturedBuffer(buffer: capturedImageBuffer)
}

@objc func saveError(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else { }
}
```

So, the RGB image is saved by this code without any issues. However, the depth map sometimes is absolutely empty (while I see a better depth map when I am rendering the depth map). So, I guess something is wrong with the `CVPixelBuffer`-to-`UIImage` conversion. I am absolutely new to Swift, and I have no clue what it can be.

I have figured out that the `CVPixelBuffer` is non-planar, so I would guess this is my issue, but neither I have any idea what to do about it, nor I have found any answer explaining how to proceed.

So, how to properly convert the non-planar `CVPixelBuffer` with `sceneDepth.depthMap` to `UIImage`?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/taking_pictures_for_3d_object_capture

From apple's sample code, apple use **CGColorSpace.linearGray** to save **depthData**.

```
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
                 error: Error?) {
    photoProcessingHandler(false)
    
    if let error = error {
        print("Error capturing photo: \(error)")
        photoData = nil
    } else {
        // Cache the HEIF representation of the data.
        photoData = photo
    }
    
    // Cache the depth data, if it exists, as a disparity map.
    // logger.log("DidFinishProcessingPhoto: photo=\(String(describing: photo))")
    if let depthData = photo.depthData?.converting(toDepthDataType:
                                                    kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32),
       let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.linearGray) {
        let depthImage = CIImage( cvImageBuffer: depthData.depthDataMap,
                                  options: [ .auxiliaryDisparity: true ] )
        depthMapData = context.tiffRepresentation(of: depthImage,
                                                  format: .Lf,
                                                  colorSpace: colorSpace,
                                                  options: [.disparityImage: depthImage])
    } else {
        logger.error("colorSpace .linearGray not available... can't save depth data!")
        depthMapData = nil
    }
}
```

Maybe you can have a try, change your code from **RGB** to **linearGray** and you can download and run the demo, capture image and compare.

I also tried using linearGray to capture image base on AVFoundation, and I found distance further than 2 meters may lead to white .tiff image.

Apple say LiDAR can work as far as 5 meters, I think maybe this distance is somehow effect by light or material of object.